# A pointwise bound for $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=\Delta u+ au$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466528/a-bound-for-the-pde-frac-partial-partial-tu-delta-u-au) I asked whether the Dirichlet PDE:
 $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u=\Delta u+ au$$ over a bounded smooth open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ has a bound in the form
$$|u(t)|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq Me^{\omega t}.$$
I wonder if we have a pointwise version of such an estimate. That is:
$$|u(t,x)|\leq M_x e^{\omega_xt}$$
where $M_x$ and $\omega_x$ are constants that may depend on $x$. I thought about using some comparison between $L^2$-norm and $L^\infty$-norm, but we only have  $$|.|_{L^2}\leq C|.|_{\infty}.$$
I don't know but I feel that only finding a closed form for the solution will solve the problem.

Comment: What spatial boundary conditions are you imposing (if any)? And what can you say about the boundary of the region? Are you saying that the boundary is a smooth manifold?

Comment: This is true, and $\omega_x$ need not depend on $x$. The main point is that the an integral norm at time $t$ controls uniform norm at times $t'>t$, due to the smoothing effect of the heat equation.  But making this precise takes work, so I'd start by looking up "parabolic maximum principle".

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567566/prove-the-estimate-ux-t-le-ce-gamma-t?rq=1